How can I delay the timer when hovering over an object?
I have a pop-up window that is open for some time specified in the timer. I need the timer to stop when I hover the cursor over the window, and continue when I move the cursor away.
this is what my setTimeout looks like:
if(this.toast.timeout){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.close()
      }, this.toast.timeout);
    }

I was thinking of using clearTimeout, but it will completely stop the timer and I do not know how to start it again from the right place. Please tell me what I can do in this situation.

I think that RxJS would be the perfect candidate for your use case.
Here is a simple example you can use to achieve what you want. Once you start to get more comfortable with it, you can improve this example :


// Get the HTML elements
const toast = document.querySelector('.toast');
const placeholder = document.querySelector('.duration');

// Declare useful variables
let totalduration = 0;
let register = true;

// Create event emitters
const timer = rxjs.timer(0, 100);
const entering = rxjs.fromEvent(toast, 'mouseenter').pipe(rxjs.startWith(null));
const leaving = rxjs.fromEvent(toast, 'mouseleave').pipe(rxjs.startWith(null));

// Listen to all event emitters
rxjs.combineLatest({
  timer,
  entering,
  leaving,
}).pipe(
  // Return if the event should register or not
  rxjs.map(() => register),
  // Only do the .subscribe if the value of register is true
  rxjs.filter(Boolean),
).subscribe(() => {
  totalduration += 0.1;
  placeholder.textContent = (Math.round(totalduration * 100) / 100) + 's';
});

// Listen to mouse events and change the register value accordingly
entering.subscribe(() => (register = false));
leaving.subscribe(() => (register = true));
.toast {
  background-color: salmon;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<div class="toast">
  Duration : <span class="duration">0s</span>
</div>




You can use HostListener to listen for events, basically start a timer on ngOnInit, on mouseenter, stop the timer, using clearTimeout, then restart it on mouseleave. Below is rough estimate of how the code will look like.
We can use a timer, that stores the last closed value and then restart the timer with the same remaining time, I used a class to do this, reference code take from this article
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export class Timer {
  t: any; /* Our timeout ID */
  startTimeout = new Date(); /* When the timer starts */
  timeLeft: number = 0; /* How much time is left */
  timeDelay = 10000; /* How long the timer should be */
  callback = () => {};

  constructor(callback = () => {}, timeDelay: number = 10000) {
    this.timeDelay = timeDelay;
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  startTimer() {
    this.startTimeout = new Date();
    this.t = setTimeout(this.callback, this.timeDelay);
  }
  pauseTimeout() {
    this.timeLeft = this.timeDelay;
    this.timeLeft -= new Date().getTime() - this.startTimeout.getTime();

    /* Clear the timer */
    if (this.t) {
      clearTimeout(this.t);
    }
  }
  resumeTimeout() {
    if (!this.timeLeft) {
      this.timeLeft = this.timeDelay;
    }
    this.t = setTimeout(this.callback, this.timeLeft);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `
    :host {display: block;
    height:100vh;}`,
  ],
  template: `{{timer?.timeLeft}}`,
})
export class App {
  timerId: any;
  timer!: Timer;

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) onEnter(e: MouseEvent) {
    this.timer?.pauseTimeout();
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) onLeave(e: MouseEvent) {
    this.timer?.resumeTimeout();
  }

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  close() {
    alert('closed');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const timeout = 10000; // this.toast.timeout;
    this.timer = new Timer(this.close.bind(this), timeout);
    this.timer.startTimer();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

The problem is that the timer should start from the place where it stopped, for example, if the window was pointed at when there were 5 seconds left, then the timer should continue from that moment on. And how did I understand this code starts the timer again?

@НикаДолгирева When the mouse leaves the popup the timer restarts using  the function startTimer mouseleave

The timer is restarting, but I need it to continue.

@НикаДолгирева updated my answer
